# Python module config not cooperating

Tags: python, config

So I'm trying to import some variable settings into my python script, as such, it currently fetches a file (config.py) from an FTP and puts it an usb stick. No issues here, however, when I try to import the config to it thells me:

> NameError: global name 'config' is not defined

A simple python script with:

```
import config

print config.status
```

yields perfect result, but this snippit won't:

```
def check_status():
        os.chdir(usb_folder)
        import config
        if config.status == "active":
                print "unitstatus set to active"
                return True
```

Can anyone put me on the right idea/track?

Comment: I am guessing config.py is in the same folder as the script you are running, and when you change directory, it can't locate config.py anymore. Try changing PYTHONPATH to include your source file or add it on programatically.

Comment: I've thought of this as well. The simple snippit indeed has the pyton file as well as the config file in the same directory. FOr the more complex script, the config file is loaded onto the usb stick, hence why i am changing directory or it won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to import the config file from another folder, you would need to add that folder to your path. You can do it programmatically using `sys.path.append()`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(usb_folder)
import config

def check_status():
    if config.status == "active":
        print "unitstatus set to active"
        return True
```